# Активность модератора

Tags: поддержка, модерация, инструменты-модератора

У любого участника в профиле можно многое узнать о его активности: когда какие сообщения писал, сколько голосовал (общее количество голосов "за" и "против"), сколько сделал правок и отметил сообщений тревогами и т.п.

Существует ли подобная информация по активности ромбового модератора? В частности, сколько тревог обработано и с каким вердиктом, сколько участников забанено и прочее, чем занимается исключительно модератор, но не рядовой участник.

В общем, хочу знать насколько тот или иной модератор бездельник.

Comment: Есть внутренняя статистика. Nick Volynkin напишет развернутый ответ с конкретными данными чуть позже. Но хотелось бы сразу предупредить - у модераторов разный ритм активности и разный подход к разгребанию тревог, так что расхождение чисел не обязательно означает, что кто-то из модераторов недорабатывает :)

Comment: @PashaPash на картинке ниже четко видна специализация: вы с Nofate тащите тревоги, а я главный по флуду. :)

Answer (score 12):

## Cтатистика за все время работы сайта.

### На основном сайте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### На Мете

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Пояснения

- Тревоги — все обработанные модератором тревоги.
- Сообщения модератора — личные сообщения участникам, могут сопровождаться блокировкой (баном)
- Сообщения на Мете —

  - вопросы / суммарный рейтинг вопросов,
  - ответы / суммарный рейтинг ответов.
- Голоса — за вопросы и ответы / против вопросов и ответов

Comment: Фотошоп? :) то есть способа посмотреть эту информацию для обычного участника нет и нужно быть ромбоносцем, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, но скриншот нотариально заверен. Не фотошоп (хотя у меня на этой странице цвета почему-то другие)

Comment: @PashaPash это у меня плагин модераторский такой, он меняет отображение некоторых элементов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin домножает результаты работы на 10? :)

Comment: @alexolut нет, добавляет пару удобных ссылок. Ну и почему-то перекрашивает кое-что. Может это для дальтоников сделано, я не знаю.

Comment: По бывшим модераторам эта статистика доступна также?

Comment: @alexolut нет, не доступна.

Comment: @alexolut а зачем она вам?

Comment: Если комментарии переносятся в чат - они учитываются в пункте "Комментариев удалено" или нет?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, учитываются. Большинство комментариев удалены именно таким образом.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а можно такую статистику каждый месяц публиковать? Или, хотя бы, за 2018 год увидеть?