# Есть ли показатели, снижение которых приводит к "увольнению" модераторов безо всяких предупреждений?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Например, количество посещений сайта в неделю: если столько то раз этот уровень был снижен у данного пользователя, то с него снимаю "погоны". Или пока сообщество явно на это не укажет?

Такие замеры существуют, они отслеживаются? Принимаются ли решения на основе оных?

Comment: Численных показателей посещаемости для модераторов нет. Построение сообщества -- это отдельная роль, на ru so недавно искали такого человека, но вакансию так и не закрыли :( Возможно, что такому человеку и были бы какие-то KPI привязаны, а вот связь работы модератора с посещаемостью сайта не так очевидна. Возможно именно поэтому такие вещи (по крайней мере до текущего) состава не доводились.

Comment: Кроме enSO - нет.

Comment: Как мне кажется, связанный вопрос: [Активность модератора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6077/176217).

Answer (score 8):

Оказывается [есть процедура снятия неактивных модераторов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338006/260198).

- Если модератор неактивен более 4 месяцев, ему отправляю письмо на почту. Если после 6 месяцев он всё ещё не активен, то будет снят с должности. По большей части это делается, т.к. у модераторов есть доступ к данным пользователей. И SE хотят как-то ограничить это дело.
- После 6 месяцев повторное письмо высылается, а также уходит уведомление управляющим сообществ.
- CM связывается с модератором и ждёт неделю.
- Если модератор отвечает, что вернётся, то всё ок. Если отвечает (или вовсе не отвечает), что у него нет времени ни сейчас, ни в ближайшем будущем, то он будет снят с должности.
- CM связываются с оставшимися модераторами по поводу нужд сообщества. Проводятся выборы новые.
- После начала выборов неактивный модератор снимается с должности.

Comment: Опять же, даже эта процедура тоже нестрого соблюдается и является лишь "направляющей", по которой могут быть приняты действия. А могут и не быть.

Comment: @AntonMenshov как обычно, в общем (: Я почитал обсуждения на многих сайтах сети на этот счёт, всё очень сложно и неоднозначно, да.

Comment: Ну все же, я думаю, что если активные модераторы сообщества свяжутся с CM - то процесс пойдет. Но сам он может очень долго не запуститься.

Comment: @AntonMenshov если оставшиеся модераторы справляются, нет смысла дёргать CM, у них и так забот хватает.

Comment: В том случае если их активных >= трех. Для маленьких сайтов, на которых всего три модератора, неактивность одного составляет серьезную проблему - даже если и нагрузка сама по себе небольшая.

Comment: @AntonMenshov могу себе представить.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что достаточно просто появляться на сайте раз в 4-е месяца, дабы "письмо" не пришло?

Comment: @edem в оригинальном посте акцент именно на "действиях". Просто появляться/отвечать на вопросы недостаточно.