# Модератор чересчур рьяно закрывает вопросы. Не пора ли его снять?

Tags: обсуждение, модераторский-произвол, вопрос-аккордеон

Небольшое предуведомление: у Модератора есть возможность (в отличие от участников с золотой меткой) **сколько угодно раз открывать и закрывать вопросы единолично**. И вопрос именно про модераторов, а не про золотые Молоты.

---

Уже не первый раз замечаю такое поведение со стороны данного модератора (один из старых **и многих** примеров: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11877/191482).

Причём закрывает вопрос со ссылкой на вовсе не дубликат, а близкий по смыслу.  Многократно, не смотря переоткрытия! Ничего лично не имею, но это неправильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Не пора ли снимать лычки за самовольное единоличное закрытие вопросов?**

---

Но произвол, не смотря на комментарий и **новое переоткрытие** - продолжается

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Ещё информация**: [Данный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1419445/191482) Модератор считает дубликатом [вот этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/480625/191482), что не является правдой. Второй про восьмеричную конкретику, в текущем - про более общее - форматы записи чисел. В связи с этим второй вопрос был отредактирован и указан заголовок более точно и узконаправленно. Однако и здесь происходит какая-то его собственная война:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На текущий момент, вопрос закрывался Grundy уже 7(!) раз несмотря на множественные голоса за переоткрытие, как автора вопроса, так и других участников и даже 2 других модераторов!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141602/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Comment: Связанный вопрос (пост?): [Теория модерации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420/1365)

Comment: Нахожу очаровательным, что единственное участике Grundy в этом вопросе — подтирание комментариев.

Comment: @Kyubey с другой стороны, единственный модератор из всех, который модерирует этот вопрос - это Грундий 

Comment: @Kyubey: Хах, прямо как в старые недобрые времена PP.

Comment: Кто хотел лично поговорить с Grundy - он вышел на контакт в чате - https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62741111#62741111

Comment: @Kromster, все что там есть - ответ в духе "я буду продолжать делать как считаю нужным, никак свои действия объяснять не буду". При таком раскладе похоже что нет смысла что-то персонально с ним обсуждать.

Comment: @Kromster, точнее, наоборот - если бы он хотел обсуждать, то смысл был бы. Спойлер: если не пытаться обсуждать, то и обсуждения не будет, так и будет "так все и так себе уже все напридумывали ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯". Вот чтобы не "напридумывали" и нужно объяснять свою позицию.

Comment: @insolor пока что я вижу как в эту играют обе стороны

Comment: @Kromster во что играют? Мы может быть что-то действительно напридумывали, но только по причине отсутствия коммуникации. Вторая сторона получается напридумывала, что мы напридумывали, поэтому даже не пытается начать коммуникацию. Вы это имеете в виду под "игрой"?)

Comment: @insolor Ну вот я пытался донести, что данных не достаточно в вопросе - меня заминусили, никаких новых данных не появилось, вопрос как был неконкретным так и остался неконкретным. Ну и мод состав морозится. Кто то кому то где то что то написал в комментариях или приватной переписке - это не считается. Прошло 2 недели, ответа нет и, скорее всего, ждать уже не стоит. Буду рад оказаться неправым здесь.

Comment: Прошло уже почти три недели со дня задания вопроса. Но ничего не изменилось: @ 
Grundy всё-таки закрыл тот вопрос, но позицию свою не объяснил. А последнее действие в этой теме - комментарий к вопросу 10 января. А сейчас 15 января. Проблема серьёзная, не уже ли про неё забыли?

Comment: Корень проблемы находится уровнем выше. Админ сайта - Nicolas Chabanovsky - забил на свои обязанности, практически не участвует в решении проблем сайта.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov у него уже давно [другие обязанности](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7545/176217). Плохо, что модераторы халявят.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov или проблема в том, что ни для модераторов, ни для админа, описанная проблема не имеет достаточной важности, чтобы её вообще решать. Все куда то что то отписывают в комментарии и лс, и ждут погоды у моря друг друга в дедлоке, чтобы либо кто то что то сделал наконец или чтобы все отвалились по таймауту =)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ - я не знал об этом. Думал, у нас по-прежнему тирания, а оказывается, давно уже демократия.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov демократия в которой нету ротации и/или регулярной ревалидации - таковой не считается =)

Comment: Связанное: [What processes exist to issue formal warnings or remove moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336173/362505)

Comment: Между прочим, и это могло быть отдельным вопросом: на enSOMeta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831 модераторы почему-то не переносят в чат даже 140+ комментариев (см. первый ответ) - видимо там понимают, когда слепое следование букве отличается от следования духу правил.

Comment: @Kromster это сюда можно приплести https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12289/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский приплетите пожалуйста, буду только рад!

Answer (score 22):

Я считаю, что показанная в вопросе деятельность **Grundy** противоречит принципам, декларируемым в посте [**Теория модерации**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420) (блог пост [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)) - как конкретным пунктам, так и по духу:

> Даже в случае активной саморегуляции иногда необходимо вмешательство модераторов. **Модераторы необходимы, чтобы обрабатывать исключительные ситуации, связанные с человеческим фактором.** Их задача — разрешать (надеемся редкие) исключительные ситуации, которые *не должны происходить* в нормальных условиях, но если такие ситуации происходят, то они могут довести все сообщество до отчаяния и полной недееспособности, если, конечно, они не будут вовремя разрешены.
>
> ...
>
> Если вы модератор одного из сообществ Stack Exchange, ниже краткий
> список того, о чем следует помнить:
>
> - Теперь, когда вы стали модератором, любые ваше действия идут от имени сообщества. Это означает, что вам необходимо придерживаться
>   наивысших стандартов поведения. Вы являетесь «послом доверия», с
>   уровнем прав аналогичным команде разработчиков и сотрудникам из
>   команды развития сообществ.
> - Ваша цель — выступать добродушным проводником сообщества, но с решимостью разрешать исключительные ситуации, при необходимости.
>   Относитесь с уважением к вашим коллегам в сообществе, что бы ни
>   произошло. Проявляйте справедливость и беспристрастность в каждом
>   вашем действии.
> - Всегда, когда это возможно, оставляйте небольшой поясняющий комментарий к каждому сообщению, в котором вы выступили (или хотели
>   выступить) в роли модератора. Крайне важно, чтобы участники сообщества
>   могли изучить нормы сообщества и практики модерирования сайта.
> - Не давайте содержимому выходить за рамках тематики сообщества: закрывайте, переносите или удаляйте вопросы, которые совершенно не
>   относятся к тематике сайта.
> - Регулярно просматривайте отмеченные тревогой сообщения и принимайте решительные действия, если они требуются.
> - В случае серьезных разногласий, связывайтесь напрямую с участником, чтобы помочь уладить конфликт интересов.

#### Какие именно проблемы я вижу:

- для решения **обыденной** ситуации (открытие-закрытие вопросов), которую сообщество может решить (и постоянно решает) самостоятельно, модератор использует свои **исключительные** права;
- модератор в данном случае не разрешает исключительную ситуацию, а создает ее сам;
- никак не обосновывает свое спорное решение по закрытию вопроса как дубликата (после первого переоткрытия модератор уже мог догадаться, что решение спорное);
- игнорирует мнение других участников (как рядовых участников, так и других модераторов);
- у меня нет информации о том, чтобы данный модератор как-то пытался уладить (*moderate*) ситуацию - на данный момент он не участвовал в обсуждении в этом вопросе, и я не видел сообщений от других участников, чтобы он с ними как-то связывался (это не означает что этого не было, но в любом случае мне об этом не известно).

#### Варианты решения:

- самый лайтовый - модератор пишет ответ с обоснованием своих действий, либо с признанием своей неправоты, после этого как-то решаем что делать дальше (по ситуации);
- участник снимается с должности модератора - самостоятельно или по решению Компании;

---

- глобальный вариант, я считаю, что он должен быть выполнен, независимо от того, будет ли реализован один из вариантов выше: **проведение перевыборов всех модераторов ruSO в 2023 году**, обязательные перевыборы каждые N лет (допустим - 3 года).

  Я вижу это решение **необходимым** для того, чтобы модераторы учитывали мнение участников сообщества, а не действовали исходя из допущения, что их частное мнение самое правильное.

  - Также, в сообществе есть 6 модераторов, но какие-то внешние признаки их деятельности мы видим только у троих (приблизительно, могу ошибаться), и у двоих модераторов последнее посещение больше месяца назад. Не понятно, то ли нам не нужно столько модераторов на самом деле, то ли (условно) трое модераторов выполняют работу за шестерых, и видимо сильно перерабатывают. Ежегодно выкладываются результаты модерации, но в них нет разбивки по модераторам, и мы вообще не можем судить о деятельности отдельных модераторов.

    При перевыборах нужно или уменьшить общее количество модераторов (исходя из информации о фактической загруженности, доступной сотрудникам), либо выбрать тоже 6 модераторов, но активно работающих.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141687/discussion-on-answer-by-insolor-------).

Answer (score 20):

Во всей этой ситуации меня больше всего раздражает не передёргивание с закрытием/переоткрытием вопроса, а отсутствие какой-либо публичной реакции от модсостава. Сам виновник "торжества" цинично переносит комментарии в чат и ничего не отвечает по сути.

> [image: Заскриню пока не замели под ковёр]

Из-за этих переносов не видно даже робких попыток Nofate отметиться в теме. Но этого всё равно очень и очень мало. Меня не покидает ощущение того, что на нас просто с презрением смотрят сверху вниз, не снисходя до возможности что-то объяснить, как-то наладить ситуацию. Как будто просто снова ждут, когда пройдёт ещё несколько дней, недель, месяцев и тема себя изживёт, забудется. Как забылись прошлые дела минувших лет. А если забылось, то и хорошо, можно ничего не делать с подобным и далее.

С момента публикации вопроса уже прошло почти две недели. Серьёзный срок, несмотря на новогодние выходные, хотя я знаю, что у многих они уже стали не такие длинные, как были ещё год назад. Около полусотни человек проголосовало, более тысячи просмотров, вопрос попал в список обсуждаемых на Мете.

> [image: Осуждаемое (sic!) на мете]

Но модераторы молчат. Поэтому **снимать надо не одного модератора, а сразу всех**. Ромб - это не только разбор тревог инструментами модератора, это ещё и нормальное человеческое взаимодействие с участниками сообщества. Но похоже, что на фоне общего загнивания сайта таких уже не осталось в текущей обойме. Некоторые поступили по чести, сняли лычки и ушли с поста, кто-то удалился совсем. А кто-то как будто просто считает это пожизненно своим, порождая иллюзию, что всё в порядке в датском королевстве, вот же они модераторы, [в списке значатся](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). Ничего менять не надо! Всё хорошо. Хотя на самом деле модераторская активность на Мете плачевно мала, а каких-то [ромбических KPI](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6077/176217) мы, наверное, больше вообще никогда здесь не увидим.

Но я всё же очень надеюсь, что ситуация скоро разрешится (кто-то снизойдёт до ответа в форме ответа) в позитивном ключе и мы снова будем жить мирно и счастливо. И руководство SO не соберётся свернуть свои русскоязычные сообщества, тогда текущая проблема с молчащими  модераторами покажется нам всем сущим пустяком.

---

Удивительно, но на следующий день после моего поста, вопрос пропал из списка "обсуждаемых на Мете". Возможно, он был удалён вручную (дабы не нагнетать?). Попробую разузнать через [большого брата](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385684/339911).
Похоже, что тревога ложная, и как раз сработал двухнедельный порог с момента публикации. В связи с этим я предлагаю [Изменить пороги попадания вопроса в список обсуждаемых на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12302/176217).

Comment: Реальный механизм запуска тотальных перевыборов существует?

Comment: @avp возможно через https://meta.stackexchange.com. Прямо прописанного механизма скорее всего нет, но если на метамете поставить вопрос, то возможно все сдвинется с мертвой точки.

Comment: Мы с Qwertiy публично обозначили позицию, несколько раз переоткрывая тот вопрос. Непублично тоже обозначили свою позицию в модераторской напрямую зачинщику. Очевидно, что проблему на нашем уровне абстракции не решить силами нашего уровня абстракции. Остаётся КМа пинговать время от времени.
Ну и я тоже как и все жду, что Grundy как-то объяснится, кроме "я с вами не согласен".

Comment: @Nofate ну вот это хорошо бы оформить ответом. И если бы это было сделано ранее - мой пост, вероятно бы, вовсе не появился. По крайней мере в текущем виде.

Answer (score 7):

Небольшой transparency апдейт от сидящих в бункере модераторов: у нас [новый КМ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1232273/emerson). Я пригласил его написать приветственный пост на Мете, надеюсь, мы его скоро увидим.

Он в курсе проблемы и поможет с решением.

Comment: А что случилось?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ в ироничном смысле? В буквальном: я два месяца взывал и мне ответили.

Comment: Во всех, наверное. Но, конечно, удивительно, если КМ назначился именно из-за этого случая. А то мы 5 лет почти без КМ живём и ничего.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ не уверен, что именно из-за этого, но Ник там теперь какими-то другими вопросами занимается.

Comment: Вроде всё теми же, [согласно таблице](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/339911).

Comment:  За что купил, за то продал

Comment: Пока всё ещё ничего нет на мете... Но поживём - увидим.

Comment: Всё ещё ждём приветственный пост..

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Приветственный пост на MSE, я думаю? Не этот ли: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381313/1345677

Comment: @Peteird не, речь шла о посте у нас. Но я, в принципе, уже не жду.

Comment: А, теперь понятно.

Comment: Ну хотя бы он не попал (пока) под волну сокращений. Но поста, и правда, ждать вряд ли стоит на ruSO.meta.

Answer (score 4):

> *""имярек" дал множество полезных ответов, внёс множество полезных правок, получил золотой знак в метке JavaScript и даже стал модератором"*, а потом, что называется, **чуть-чуть потерял берега**.

Думаю, спустя столько времени (6 недель!) после породившего тему инцидента, можно сказать (пункты идут хронологически):

- огорчает, конечно, предшествующее поведение "имярека", которому следовало бы придерживаться подхода невмешательства чуть больше ("не терять берега"). Просят вопрос не закрывать, не нарушает вопрос правила, не согласен ТС с правками, другие модераторы не поддерживают - в любом из этих случаев остановись, отпусти, успокойся.
- огорчает слабость текущего сформулированного поста, скудность прикрепленного материала и желтизна заголовка. За прошедшие недели особо ничего не поменялось, кроме диалогов в комментариях. Не такого качества тезиса и аргументации с доказательствами ожидаешь на Мете от участников с 10к+ репутации. Да и глупо, предлагать снятие по представленным 2 примерам (читай ниже).
- сильно огорчает реакция "имярека" и мод.состава, а точнее её фактическое отсутствие. Причем как в ключе призыва "имярека" к порядку, так и в ключе сглаживания конфликта. Такое ощущение, что с точки зрения мод.состава, у них идет отсиживание в бункере, пока народ с вилами не разойдется. Тогда как более правильным для площадки, в долгосрочной перспективе, было бы договариваться и примирять.

Comment: А кто такой ТС?)

Comment: @EzioMercer ТС = TS = TopicStarter = автор темы. Иногда еще называемый OP (Original Poster)

Comment: Спасибо! Алексей забанен???? За что? Что я пропустил?)

Comment: @EzioMercer все что-то пропустили. Похоже был однодневный бан. Не факт что к вопросу это вообще имеет какое-то отношение.

Comment: @insolor Я тоже думал что не с этим вопросов был свзяан бан т.к. тогда давным давно забанили бы :) Но всё равно интересно что такого могло произойти что до бана дошло

Comment: @EzioMercer надо же, Алексей снова забанен, уже на 7 дней... Но согласен с `@insolor`.

Comment: @Зонтик Было бы намного лучше, если бы ещё причина блокировки писалась бы и ссылка нарушение (если это возможно), а то так не понятно что случилось, с чего началось и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Раз в комментариях опять возникла "жизнь", выскажу своё мнение по этому поводу.

Участник `@Grundy` дал множество полезных ответов, внёс множество полезных правок, получил золотой знак в метке `JavaScript` и даже стал модератором.
После всех этих достижений такое поведение выглядит очень странно..

Тут проблема вовсе не в том, что модератор закрыл что-то не то, а в том, что он проигнорировал мнение двух модераторов, автора вопроса и многих других участников. И всё-таки закрыл вопрос. Более того, `@Grundy` "Расширил список дубликатов":

[image: расширение списка дубликатов]

И если до этого вопрос мог быть дубликатом (но сообщество вроде решило, что это не так), то [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453059/%d0%a7%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%85%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5) этот вопрос например в списке дубликатов **явно лишний**.

Кстати, я понял, что имел в виду @Grundy [в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62743643#62743643). Просто на выборах-2017 он [обещал банить, переносить комментарии в чат и закрывать вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6051/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-2017-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0/6121#6121).
Например:

> **Вопрос:** Как вы поступите, если увидите «комментарий–шутку», смешную только автору комментария, от давно известного вам участника сообщества, с которым вы находитесь в приятельских отношениях?

> **Ответ**: Вопрос - закрою, комментарии - почищу, знакомому - бан

Но это же вроде не основание для нарушения "Теории модерации".

**P.S** я просто излагаю своё мнение, а не "имею претензии к @Grundy в ситуации, которые меня вообще не касаются".

Comment: В этом нет ничего поразительного. Если администрация считает, что проблемы нет, ничего и не будет сделано. Если на мнение топовых участников в свое время плевали, то один вопрос-дубликат по основам Javascript - это такая мелочь, что смешно и говорить.

Comment: "*@Grundy дал множество полезных ответов, внёс множество полезных правок, получил золотой знак в метке JavaScript и даже стал модератором*", а потом, что называется, **чуть-чуть потерял берега**.

Comment: @Kromster Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; берега перемещены в чат.

Comment: @Зонтик и какой вывод вашего ответа? Что не нужно ничего пытаться делать, все - зря, жизнь - тлен?

Comment: @insolor наоборот, это нельзя так оставлять

Comment: Вопросу больше полугода. К чему эта бесполезная правка в Октябре - непонятно.

Comment: @Kromster поднял вопрос, похожая тема [всплыла недавно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13087/532877).

Comment: Ну так тогда и напишите (например новый ответ) - со словами, мол "недавно опять всплыла тема, и вот что я хочу сказать" )

Answer (score -3):

> Данный вопрос Модератор считает дубликатом вот этого, что не является правдой. Второй про восьмеричную конкретику, в текущем - про более общее - форматы записи чисел.

Это похоже поиск формального повода назвать вопрос не дубликатом. В сущности, оба вопроса про числовые литералы в разных системах счисления, один из них чуть более узкий, а другой - более широкий. На оба из них лучший ответ - это раздел документации языка по числовым литералам, его надо читать полностью для нормального понимания темы. Поэтому они совершенно точно дубликаты, но вопрос в том, в каком направлении лучше закрывать. В одном более подробно описано, а в другом есть ссылки на документацию и спецификацию.

Так что я думаю, надо не снимать Grundy, а сделать в одном из вопросов исчерпывающий ответ и закрыть все похожие вопросы на него.

Comment: Вот эти вот рассуждения и должны были бы быть в голове модератора при первом же закрытии. А вместо этого имеем карнавал из 7(!) закрытий. Как мне кажется для модератора такое поведение .. сомнительно, мягко говоря.

Comment: Логика тут имеет заметный изъян - "Это похоже поиск формального повода назвать вопрос не дубликатом. В сущности, оба вопроса про **словари/вектора/правила в разных ситуациях**, один из них чуть более узкий, а другой - более широкий. На оба из них лучший ответ - это раздел документации языка по **соответствующим темам**, его надо читать полностью для нормального понимания темы. Поэтому они совершенно точно дубликаты". То что вопросы частично пересекаются в ответах - не делает их дубликатами. Из них *можно* слепить один более общий (как он еще пытался, добавив про `e`, но это тоже от лукавого)

Comment: Почему же тогда вы должны отвечать за Grundy? Если Grundy знает причину почему мой вопрос дубликат, пусть опишет её либо в комментариях к моему вопросу, либо тут. Если сообщество решит что Grundy прав значит мой вопрос закроют навсегда и таких дискуссий на Мете будет меньше, почему же он тогда этого не делает? Причины нет? Пока что я вижу это как использование своих полномочий в личных целях (А модераторы должны работать с сообществом, а не против него). Также прошу указать в "оригинальном" **вопросе** (`Числа, начинающиеся с нуля, в JavaScript`) хоть слово про *не* восьмеричные литералы.

Comment: С вопросом как таковым никаких проблем нет. Он может быть дубликатом или нет - но сообщество само может решить, закрыть его дубликатом или переоткрыть. Проблема начинается в тот момент, когда один участник с правами модератора начинает думать, что его мнение самое правильное, правильнее мнения нескольких десятков обычных участников и модераторов, переоткрывавших вопрос, и с упорством Сизифа все закрывает и закрывает вопрос как дубликат. Если бы этот участник не занимался такими вещами, то и никакой проблемы бы не возникло, вопрос бы может быть закрыли (или нет), и давно забыли бы про него.

Answer (score -3):

Исходя из **приведенных** фактов:

- не вижу ни одной причины, почему нужно ставить вопрос о снятии модератора
- вижу небольшой конфликт при закрытии\переоткрытии\оформлении дубликатов.

В будущем:

- абсолютно точно будут возникать ситуации, когда решение или действие некоторого модератора будет противоречить консенсусу сообщества.
- Мета (Ru.SO) — это механизм разрешения таких конфликтов. Написание поста о том, почему некий вопрос должен быть закрыт\открыт определенным образом — это одно из прямых предназначений нашей с вами меты. Давайте ее использовать для этого.

Итого:

"*Самовольное* единоличное закрытие нескольких вопросов" — не повод снятия с модераторской должности. Особенно, если прецедента обсуждения и откровенного противоречия модератора сообществу не выявлено на мете по конкретному вопросу.

Comment: "Особенно, если прецедента обсуждения и откровенного противоречия модератора сообществу не выявлено на мете по конкретному вопросу." - ну то есть как? Множественное повторное закрытие вопроса модератором после переоткрытия его участниками - это не противоречие? "не повод снятия с модераторской должности" - хорошо, допустим. Тогда как решить противоречие? Запретить модератору закрывать вопросы дубликатами? Что-то я сомневаюсь, что такая настройка прав возможна. Строго погрозить пальчиком, и сказать, чтобы учитывал мнение других участников, а то будет "ай-яй-яй"?

Comment: "Мета (Ru.SO) — это механизм разрешения таких конфликтов." - так и есть. Я вижу, что участники пытаются как-то решить конфликт, но я не вижу никаких признаков, чтобы Grundy как-то в этом участвовал. Одностороннее решение конфликта только стороной обычных участников невозможно, а вторая сторона просто уклоняется от участия.

Comment: *Конечно же, перенос комментариев под вопросом в чат не является участием в решении конфликта*

Answer (score -13):

Если честно, я не понял ажиотажа.

Модератор не так что-то закрыл и не там, теперь поднимаем БУНД? Видели уже, плавали.

Прокомментировали, а модератор посмел все еще делать так, как считает нужным? На кол его! Но не для этого ли мы выбираем модераторов, чтобы они делали как считают нужным?

Сколько вопросов модератор закрыл так, что автору не понравилось? Два? Это точно повод поднимать бучу? Или это кликбейт такой?

Чтобы вообще заикаться о каких то снятиях модераторов, я думаю, двух примеров не достаточно. Он что, правило какое нарушил на сайте? Вроде нет. Мы, как айтишники, должны основывать свои суждения на репрезентативных данных, а не потому что "АААА, ВСЕ ПРОПАЛО".

Просто имхо, если поднимать вопросы о снятии модераторов, то будьте любезны провести какой то хотя бы анализ его действий. Сколько вопросов он закрыл? Сколько закрыл не так как, вам нравится? Сколько было переоткрыто? Другими словами, какую то количественную величину его пользы/вреда за время. Всё остальное ваши личные ощущения.

А если вам конкретный вопрос не нравится как закрыли, то надо об этом и беседовать, а не о снятии лычек.

Ну и не ясно, что тут обсуждать? Хотим привлечь модераторов к проблеме? Вроде если они друг другу открывашки/закрывашки кидают, то они уже в курсе и сами в состоянии друг с другом связаться.

Потому я бы и этот вопрос либо закрыл (был бы модератором, как "нельзя дать объективный ответ") или переформулировал с указанием конкретной проблемы в конкретном вопросе, а не просто крик души.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141638/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167------).