# Стоит ли отказаться от переноса комментариев в чат на Мете?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, комментарии, перенос-комментариев-в-чат

Есть дискуссионный вопрос на Мете с меткой [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) (оригинал - [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)) и есть функционал переноса комментариев в чат с пометкой «Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии», например:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоит ли отказаться от применения такого функционала в дискуссионных вопросах? Можно ли интерпретировать поведение модератора как попытку «притормозить» дискуссию, «спустить её на тормозах»?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141896/discussion-on-question-by------).

Comment: Согласен с @Grundy - а то уже километр комментариев вода в ступе толчется

Comment: Ну, значит, эта дискуссия, как и 99% остальных переносов в чат, останется мною непрочитанной :)

Answer (score 7):

> Стоит ли отказаться от применения такого функционала в дискуссионных вопросах?

**Возможно. Однако я бы оставил это на усмотрение модераторов.** Иногда (безотносительно конкретного примера приведенного в этом вопросе) стоит убрать всю или часть дискуссии в комментарии. [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) разумеется подразумевает обсуждение. Однако, я не интерпретирую это возможностью бесконечно обсуждения и полемики в комментариях. Поэтому, **жесткое правило** здесь точно будет во **вред**.

> Можно ли интерпретировать поведение модератора как попытку «притормозить» дискуссию, «спустить её на тормозах»?

**Можно, но не стоит**. При наличии обширной дискуссии в комментариях, модератору прилетает флаг автоматически, который разрешается одной кнопкой.

Однако, я бы скорее обратил внимание на следующее: при наличии вопроса, который напрямую касается одного из модераторов (будь то мета или основной сайт), **хорошим тоном** для данного модератора считается не участвовать в модерировании данного вопроса и **отдать его на откуп другим модераторам**, чтобы "модераторское действие\бездействие" было применено стороной наиболее "незаинтересованной".

Comment: Да в целом тревоги в адрес одного из модераторов - это явный конфликт интересов, и они не должны обрабатываться этим же модератором.

Answer (score 6):

> Можно ли интерпретировать поведение модератора как попытку «притормозить» дискуссию, «спустить её на тормозах»?

Я так не думаю. Скорее всего, модераторы поступают в таких случаях довольно шаблонно. Вообще, я считаю, что переносить в чат дискуссии в таких случаях нужно, когда комментариев действительно много (более 20 - 25 штук). Когда комментариев слишком много, смотреть ответы очень неудобно.

`мета` - это сайт именно для обсуждений, поэтому переносить в отдельный чат дискуссию меньше 20 комментариев не стоит. Это не касается основного сайта, на нём 10 комментариев - уже много, ведь это не сайт обсуждений, а лишь сайт вопросов и ответов по программированию.

Мне кажется, что модератор не хотел сделать ничего плохого, а лишь пытается таким способом улучшить сайт. Иногда, правда, модераторы могут "перестараться", но обижаться на это серьёзно не стоит =).

А вообще, лучше решить этот вопрос с самим модератором, попытайтесь договориться с ним на этот счёт, чтобы всё уладить.

Comment: Предположения о добрых намерениях модератора это отлично, но и какая-то обратная связь от него тоже бы не помешала :)

Comment: Насчет "шаблонно", это в самую точку. См. ответ Антона, при появлении достаточного числа комментариев модератору приходит тревога, в ответ на которую можно перенести комментарии в чат. То есть сам сайт поощряет такой способ модерации. Нюанс в том, что на мете видать только Grundy проверяет тревоги, поэтому может создаться впечатление, что это некий заговор от него по снесению неугодных комментариев. На деле же ничего особенного не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Мне очень нравится, что огромное количество комментариев можно перемещать в чат. Если обусждение очень долгое, то чат в разы удобнее чем комментарии

Каких-то "злых" намерений у кого-то модератора я уверен что нет. Да и бессмысленно так думать, т.к. насколько я знаю в чатах нет никаких ограничений чтобы высказать свою точку зрения - это я по поводу того, что комментарии можно оставлять если есть 50 репутации, а в чатах вроде не видел ограничений

Функционал насколько я знаю одинаковый как на мете так и на основном сайте, потому вряд ли уберут такую возможность и/или добавлять всякие проверки на наличие каких-то меток в вопросе я уверен что не станут

Иногда может быть такое, что комментариев +- 7-8 штук и их кидают в чат, хоть это и может быть неудобным, но спорить с таким решением любого модератора я бы не стал

Comment: К сожалению, при переносе в чат теряются голоса «за». И полезные комментарии могут стать незаметны. Хорошо бы как минимум изменить логику переноса по умолчанию. Чтобы заплюсованные комментарии оставались, например.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Не знаю как другие читают комментарии, но лично я не обращаю внимания на голоса "за". Если я уже зашёл в чат, то уже читаю всё подряд. Если 50 людям понравился какой-то комментарий, то вообще не означает, что мне это тоже понравится, потому эти голоса для меня вообще не важны, важно содержание :) Да и несколько раз видел, как шуточные комментарии набирают несколько голосов "за", они явно не несут какой-то пользы, просто удачная шутка. Не зря голоса "за" в комментариях никак не учитываются в репутации

Comment: @αλεχολυτ [по теме вашего комментария: upvotes to comments -> to stars in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259469/383809)

Comment: @AntonMenshov ага, у меня там даже апвоуты присутствуют.

Answer (score -2):

Часто замечал, особенно на Мете (и в т.ч. за собой), что в комментариях начинается обсуждение, аргументация, попытки ответов.

Справка нам говорит:

> Используйте комментарии, чтобы получить дополнительную информацию или уточнить вопрос или ответ.

То есть, как я это интерпретирую, в комментариях стоит лишь уточнять вопрос, а вот обсуждать его (*"расширенная дискуссия"*) правильнее либо в чате, либо постить обстоятельный ответ.

То есть, по-хорошему, вопрос должен быть четко сформулирован (и обсуждение в комментариях должно этому помогать), и тогда на него можно будет давать обстоятельный ответ (которому опять же комментарии помогают стать лучше).

Можно руководствоваться тем, что после завершения обсуждения (и внесения правок по его результатам), удаление комментариев не должно приводить к какой-либо потере ценности вопроса/ответа.

Comment: Для основного сайта - это безусловно правдиво. Но мне кажется, что условие «мета + дискуссия» могло бы несколько изменить подход.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Вам следует уточнить вопрос этими подробностями

Comment: Так это уже есть в тексте, и было там с самого начала.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ок, значит вопрос больше о конкретно этом