# Сбор вопросов для будущих кандидатов в модераторы сообщества 2023

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

> **Цель этого треда в сборе вопросов для анкеты кандидатов в модераторы. Анкета сейчас доступна [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5#questionnaire).**

---

Через неделю (2023-04-04) в сообществе Stack Overflow на русском [начнутся выборы модераторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5).
В связи с этим мы планируем провести сессию вопросов и ответов с кандидатами в модераторы. Сессия даёт возможность участникам сообщества задать интересующие их вопросы кандидатам. Участие полностью добровольное.

Вот как это пройдёт:

- До начала фазы выдвижения (2023-04-04 20:00:00Z UTC либо 4:00 pm EDT того же дня) этот вопрос будет открыт, и любой участник сообщества может предложить свой вопрос к кандидатам в модераторы ответом к этому вопросу. Пожалуйста, добавляйте *один вопрос к кандидатам в одном ответе*.
- Если ваш вопрос содержит ссылку, пожалуйста используйте соответсвующую разметку, это облегчит составление итогового опросника.
- Это прекрасная возможность обозначить вопросы, которые важны именно вам, и "подсветить" текущие проблемы.
- Команда развития сообществ предоставит небольшой набор базовых вопросов. Первые два из них обязательно войдут в список вопросов кандидатам:

  - Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?
  - Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?
- Команды развития сообщества также включит следующие три вопроса, если вы не соберете достаточно вопросов:

  - Что, по вашему мнению, делает модератор?
  - «Ромб» будет добавлен ко всему, что вы говорите и говорили в прошлом, включая вопросы, ответы и комментарии, а все, что вы сделаете в будущем, будет оценено под другим ракурсом. Что вы думаете по этому поводу?
  - Каким образом статус модератора сделает ваши действия более эффективными в сравнении с ситуацией, когда вы просто [наберете 10](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) или [20 тысяч баллов репутации](/help/privileges/trusted-user)?
- Через неделю, с началом фазы выдвижения, команда развития сообществ выберет **до 8 вопросов от участников сообщества, набравших наибольшее количество голосов**. Эти вопросы будут использоваться в дополнение к двум вышеупомянутым обязательным вопросам. Команда развития сообществ оставляет за собой право вносить правки в вопросы так, чтобы они соответствовали выборам. В любом случае, если возникнут какие-либо замечания по содержанию вопросов, мы постараемся описать их в виде комментариев, дав автору возможность внести изменения.
- Как только сообщество определится с вопросами, будет создан новый вопрос, предназначенный для сбора ответов от кандидатов.
- Сессия вопросов и ответов — это прекрасная возможность понять, как кандидат смотрит на существующие в настоящий момент проблемы нашего сообщества. Хотите что–то узнать о будущем модераторе нашего сообщества? Добавьте ответ к этой публикации содержащий любой вопрос, который вы хотите задать кандидату.

Если у вас есть вопросы о выборах, пожалуйста, оставьте **комментарий к этому вопросу**.

Comment: @Nofate, почему здесь написано, что начало выборов 4 апреля, а вы [писали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12418/%d0%90-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b/12483#12483), что 28 марта?

Comment: @wchistow он писал о начале кампании. Я бы предложил воспринимать это как появление [страницы выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5).

Comment: @wchistow выборы состоят из нескольких фаз: сбор вопросов, выдвижение, праймериз (не всегда) и собственно выборы. 28 марта начался весь процесс и первая фаза.

Comment: На этот пост кто-то поставил минус `о_O` ....

Comment: @Зонтик на вопросе где предлагались выборы тоже были минусы

Comment: @Danis и не просто сколько-то минусов, а ровно столько минусов, сколько сейчас на этом вопросе.

Comment: @Nofate почему в анкету попали 10 вопросов, хотя в тексте упоминается 8?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ
> Эти вопросы будут использоваться в дополнение к **двум** вышеупомянутым

Comment: @Nofate omg, вот я слепень.

Comment: Should this post be locked due to starting the election?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ No, we don't generally lock these posts. At least, not on the rest of the network - we never have.

Answer (score 17):

Может ли репутация участника повлиять на Ваше решение в каком-либо вопросе и почему?
Если да, то в каких случаях и на что она может повлиять?
Есть ли другие факторы, которые могут оказать на Вас влияние?
*(Например: данные участника, мнения или информация, представленная третьими лицами и т.п.)*

Comment: "Есть ли другие факторы, которые могут оказать на Вас влияние?" - можешь пожалуйста это конрктизировать? Мне не очень понятно, какой примерный список ты ожидаешь увидеть. Например если ты ожидаешь тут увидеть что-то типа "настроение может повлиять", то этого не будет перечислено, хотя в дейтсвительности может быть. Но допустим можно спросить может ли повлиять на решение прошлые "судимости" участника на сайте и т.д.? Т.е. под "факторы" имеется ввиду данные участника или что-то что связанно с самим модератором?

Comment: @EzioMercer, речь идет о данных участника, мнениях или информации, представленной третьими лицами и т.п. Настроение в данный список я точно не включаю. С одной стороны оно априори не должно иметь влияния. С другой стороны такое категоричное мнение мне кажется немного утопичным. UPD: дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 16):

В каких случаях, по Вашему мнению, полномочия модератора должны быть безусловно отозваны/отменены?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то на этот вопрос есть ответ где-то в FAQ

Comment: @EzioMercer тут вопрос не про правила, а про личное мнение)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Я понимаю, но оно не несёт никакого смысла (как минимум для меня) т.к. от этого ничего меняется. Чтобы отвечаюзий не считал, полномочия будут сняты по описанным правилам :)

Answer (score 11):

Зачем вам модераторство, если имея 10к+ репутации на площадке и так можно заниматься улучшениями вопросов и ответов, работать с метками, очередями проверок и т.п. и т.д. Какого именно инструментария вам не хватает и для чего он вам необходим?

Comment: очень похожий вопрос уже есть в дефолтных

Comment: @МихаилРебров не настаиваю, если есть - то можно и объединить или мой заигнорить.

Comment: @Kromster Просто есть риск, что не заигнорят, и другие интересные вопросы не попадут в опросник. Например, мне нравиться вопрос про неудачное модерирование. Что-то он мало голосов набрал, а этот (похожий на дефодтный) - много. И опросник будет не такой интересный...

Comment: @МихаилРебров вопрос из дефолтных будет добавлен только в том случае, если мы не наберём достаточного количества вопросов.

Answer (score 7):

Стоит ли, по Вашему мнению, ограничивать срок работы модератора?
Опишите как Вы относитесь к сменяемости модераторского состава.

Answer (score 6):

Какие проблемы сайта вы видите в настоящий момент? Что можно сделать для того, чтобы их решить?

Answer (score 5):

Модерирование - тяжелая и продолжительная работа. Сколько по-вашему модератор должен уделять сообществу своего личного времени ежедневно/еженедельно? Как бы вы боролись с усталостью от своих обязанностей, если бы она возникла?

Answer (score 4):

В каких случаях вы будете вмешиваться в решении какого-нибудь конфликта в сообществе?
В каких случаях доверите принятие решения участникам?

Comment: Немного абстрактно)

Comment: @Зонтик мне кажется в данном случае - это не плохо, даёт возможность кандидату раскрыть свои мысли по поводу конфликтных ситуаций более глубоко, что упростит принятие решения об отдаче голоса

Comment: На мой взгляд вмешиваться модератор должен в любом случае, т.к. это, как Вы указали в вопросе, конфликт. Но, сдаётся мне, что работа модераторов и заключается в том, чтоб не доводить до конфликтов.

Comment: @XelaNimed иногда бывает когда модераторы не вмешивается и участники решают этот конфликт не хуже. Думаю такие решения лучше, чем если пришел бы модератор и забанил бы половину на день, да бы успокоится.

Answer (score 4):

Каким был ваш последний неудачный(!) опыт модерирования? Опишите ситуацию, что вы сделали неправильно, и как удалось разрешить ситуацию?

**если вы ранее не модерировали, то вспомните пример из своей практики приближенный к модерации*

Comment: Вы случайно не проводите собеседования в FAANG? :)

Comment: @nomnoms12 нет, а что? Имхо признание собственных ошибок это ценный опыт для модератора.

Answer (score 3):

Как ваша работа будучи модератором сможет положительно повлиять на сообщество?
Что уникального и полезного вы можете привнести?

Comment: Похожий вопрос есть в дефолтных ("Что, по вашему мнению, делает модератор?") ....

Comment: @Зонтик нет, это разные вопросы, примерно как "зачем нужен язык программирования?" и "чем хорош python?"

Comment: Как по мне "уникальность" - не должно быть вообще, каждый модератор старается делать сообщество лучше и все их обязанности заранее известны, потому чего-то уникального не может быть.  "Что полезного вы можете привнести?" - по-моему работа модератора впринципе заключетсся в том чтобы внести полезность, вопрос очень расплывчатый как по мне, ну или ответ будет просто перечислением обязанностей модераторов. Потому не вижу впринципе смысла в вашем вопросе

Comment: @EzioMercer так, еще раз, вопрос более глобальный. Он не про обязанности модератора, и не эквивалентен "что вы вообще будете делать став модератором?", а о том, что можете привнести лично вы, кандидатур много, чем вы отличаетесь от других кандидатов? Или все модераторы будут делать одно и то же и особо нет разницы кто им станет раз список обязанностей фиксированный? (намек на человеческие качества и личные убеждения)

Answer (score 1):

Будете ли вы переносить комментарии в чат на мете? Стоит ли отказаться от применения такого функционала в дискуссионных вопросах? Можно ли интерпретировать такое поведение модератора как попытку «притормозить» дискуссию, «спустить её на тормозах»?

[Оригинал вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12289/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: Вроде бы наболевший вопрос, и его логично задать....

Answer (score 1):

Что по Вашему мнению важнее - решение проблемы одного человека сейчас или решение проблем многих в будущем?

Comment: А одно мешает другому?

Answer (score 0):

Согласны ли вы с тем, что сообщество не нуждается в выделенном управляющем и с тем, что сообщество может без посторонней помощи решать проблемы и модерировать сайт?

Answer (score -3):

Если бы модераторов вознаграждали, то какая награда, как вам кажется была бы справедливой?

- Репутация
- Дополнительные достижения, которые могут получить только модераторы.
- Личный рейтинг модератора отдельно от основной репутации.
- Рейтинг доверия сообщества

---