# Изменить пороги попадания вопроса в список обсуждаемых на Мете

Tags: предложение, мета, обсуждаемое-на-мете

Список "обсуждаемых на Мете" вопросов (отображаемый с правой стороны страницы с вопросами) формируется по определённым правилам. [Они перечислены](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/339911) на MSE. Одно из правил - вопрос должен быть опубликован не более 2 недель назад. Т.е. по истечении 2 недель, вопрос пропадает из "обсуждаемого". Также сказано, что эти правила можно подкорректировать на уровне сайта.

В силу достаточно большой латентности ruSO, предлагаю увеличить этот интервал хотя бы до месяца.

Comment: Так можно, конечно, нагонять побольше трафика на Мету, но ведь, скажем так, не очень бинайсный модератор все равно сможет отуда убрать пост.

Comment: @Nofate я очень надеюсь, что для обсуждения у нас будут не только темы про грехи модераторов :)

Comment: Просто на что-то важное можно повесить [meta-tag:важное], а тема месячной давности уже не будет особенно горячей.

Comment: С другой стороны, можно использовать data driven подход: собрать статистику времени "жизни" мета-постов  на https://data.stackexchange.com/rume/

Answer (score 4):

Я согласен с [комментарием Nofate](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12302/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5#comment53228_12302). Использование тэга [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5) уже позволяет донести важную информацию или обратить внимание сообщества на важное обсуждение.

Разумеется, это требует действия со стороны Community Manager или модераторов, но, это скорее хорошо, чем плохо. Слишком много "важного", "обсуждаемого" и вообще океан уведомлений в интерфейсе я считаю чрезмерным.

Таким образом, **я не считаю необходимым** подкручивать дефолтный критерий вопросов, попадающий в "Обсуждаемые на мете".

Comment: Слишком много и не возьмётся. Портянки справа в любом случае не будет, может быть ротация только. Но сейчас проблема другая - несмотря на "важность и обсуждаемость" ссылки на вопрос просто НЕТ.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Какой именно вопрос так сильно волнует, про Грундия?)

Comment: @EzioMercer это должно быть очевидно по голосам, просмотрам и (невыполнению уже) формальных критериев попадания в список обсуждаемого.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Если вопрос возник из-за вопроса с Грундием, то у него более 1к просмотров, так что думаю все кому надо уже в курсе и постоянно показывать этот вопрос на всех страницах справа не вижу абсолютно никакого смысла. Тем более все сверху оповещены, не вижу никакого смысла продолжать всем этот вопрос показывать

Comment: @EzioMercer совершенно не важно из-за чего вопрос возник. Предложение не про конкретный вопрос, а настройки по умолчанию на весь сайт. Это странно, когда на enSO и ruSO определённые пороги одинаковые при отличающейся в сотню раз аудитории.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Даже если не рассматривать конкретный вопрос, то видеть месяц один и тот же вопрос я бы явно не хотел. Те кто регулярно заходят на сайт увидят вопрос за 2 недели уж точно, если же там есть активность, то в главной мете он будет пока есть активность и это вполне достаточно. Не знаю как большинство, но когда захожу на ruSO, то обязательно чекаю и мету. Так что все кому надо и кто активный участник явно увидит вопрос за 2 недели. А. если ещё и вопрос действительно интересный, то думаю и без напоминалки справа люди будут смотреть что там нового/интересного

Comment: @αλεχολυτ имхо, лучше бы потратили время на поиск конкретики (список вопросов которые модератор перезакрывал наперекор), а то щас там их сколько всего - 2? Это ни о чем.