# Но ведь это не дубликат

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты, модераторский-произвол

[В чем разница между ref out in?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1547335/)

В данном вопросе спрашивается про in, out и ref, а в "дубликате" только out и ref

При этом об in в ответе на дубликат вообще ни о чём не говорится

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149294/discussion-on-question-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.