# Вопрос к модераторам - Сколько времени отнимают модераторские обязанности?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, выборы

Интересно было бы узнать у тех, кто уже хлебнул этого лиха, сколько времени, скажем, в неделю отнимают у них модераторские обязанности?

Просто, как мне кажется, кандидаты не очень знают о том, во что ввязываются — если, конечно, относиться к работе всерьез.

Впрочем, как и все остальные участники.

Например, есть вопрос о том, как вы будете решать разногласия с другими модераторами. Но для ответа типа "в личной переписке" или там "модераторском чате" надо знать об их существовании.

По-моему, требуется какая-то большая осведомленность в конкретных деталях о том, что это за работа. Упаси Боже, я не выдвигаюсь, с меня хватило еще Фидошного опыта... — но я задал себе вопрос: а если бы я сейчас решил выдвинуться в модераторы? — и понял, что никакой конкретики о том, что это за работа, сколько надо посвящать ей времени, и какие инструменты у них есть — я не в курсе. Получается, все мы покупаем кота в мешке? :)

Comment: Уже который раз я встречаю подобный вопрос. Можете пожалуйста уточнить что помимо того что описано в [FAQ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) и на [мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7420/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8) вас интересует? Что там не написано и должно быть освещено, кроме как "Сколько времени это отнимает в среднем (к примеру в день/неделю)?" ?

Comment: Независимо от того, сколько времени я трачу, все тревоги все равно обработает @Grundy.
Но я уже писал недавно в одном из обсуждений: нет конкретных требований, каждый приносит пользу в меру своих сил. (Но хотя бы час в неделю надо тратить, чтобы просто оставаться в контексте происходящего).

Comment: @EzioMercer В вашем ответе меня заинтересовала ваша реакция на вопрос, в первую очередь как кандидата в модераторы. А в целом — "мы многое из книжек узнаем, а истины передают изустно". На 95% (число условное) вопросов на ruSO можно точно так же ответить — что помимо того, что написано в учебниках и Интернете, вас интересует? :)

Comment: @Harry Конечно же можно :) Но учитывая опыт таких учистников как вы, мне становится интересно что именно вы не нашли среди того что уже описанно. И я свой вопрос спрашивал не как упрёк типа "иди и почитай", ни в коем случае! Просто лично для меня исходя из правил и описаний всё довольно ясно, но возможно я чего-то не знаю и/или не учитываю и потому считаю что мне всё понятно. И мне было интересно, объяснения чему вы не нашли среди того что уже есть. Потому что для вас это явно не первые выборы модераторов, но даже у вас видимо остались вопросы. Потому и стало интересно :)

Comment: Возможно, я как модератор, потом добавлю это всё в FAQ/Справки, чтобы другие участники потом не задавались тем же вопросам что и вы :)

Comment: Андрей Апанасик где-то подробно на этот вопрос отвечал, насколько я помню

Comment: @МихаилРебров я думаю, вы имеете ввиду [статью на Habr](https://habr.com/ru/articles/483254/).

Comment: @EzioMercer Понимаете, это примерно как сравнивать должностные обязанности и реальную работу. Учебник и реальные задачи. Стандарт языка и его идиомы :) Словом, мне это напомнило комсомольскую юность :) — сплошные лозунги и совершенно иная жизнь.

Comment: @Harry, хороший вопрос, стоило выдвинуться!

Answer (score 16):

Лично у меня от часа в день на SO уходило, когда я модератором был. Если за день были только тревоги, то поменьше. Но если происходили какие-то драмы, то и по нескольку часов могло уходить, если в чатах шло обсуждение или нужно было на Мете пилить пост.

Много времени отнимают кейсы, когда нужно отследить мультовода и всех его твинков. Инструменты у модераторов за целый год модерства не улучшили. Могу предположить, что они до сих пор довольно неудобные.

По сути, я в текущих выборах и не участвую, т. к. вряд ли получится столько времени выделять.

Comment: Вот этот вопрос надо было задавать кандидатам — готовы ли вы тратить полный рабочий день в неделю на выполнение своих функций...

Comment: @Harry еще не вечер. Комментарии под кандидатурами открыты. Вы можете их задать. Они для этих целей и созданы (дебаты, ответы на вопросы). Ну и есть кандидаты, которые и без вопроса понимали куда они идут ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @МихаилРебров Каждому из 14 кандидатов? Слишком много работы :) И потом, всегда выбирают не тех, кто лучше всего сможет справиться с работой, а тех, кто лучше всего сможет пройти выборы...

Comment: @Harry почему нет? Отдельные участники уже делали так на этих выборах

Comment: @Harry мне кажется, само проведение *реальных* выборов очень полезная вещь для всех их участников (и даже просто наблюдателей). Даже если будет выбран условный "проходитель" - его всегда можно снять, это послужит хорошим примером для всех.

Answer (score 3):

Я здесь не модератор, но мне кажется очевидным, что как и любая добровольная "работа", эта - отнимает **ровно столько времени, сколько на нее выделяется**. У кого-то это 0 часов в год, у кого-то - длительные приступы энтузиазма по 8 часов в сутки месяцами.

Ближайшая аналогия, которую можно привести - *"Сколько времени отнимает быть участником ruSO с 213к репутации?"*. Ответ будет - *"Да сколько угодно! От 0 до 24/7 без сна и отдыха"*.

По-хорошему, КМ или другие над-модераторские лица (в т.ч. коллективный запрос) должны проводить ревизию деятельности модераторов и периодически рассматривать вопрос о соответствии должности (по активности, по соблюдению правил и т.п.). Иначе, мы имеем то что имеем - из 5 модераторов активны примерно 2,5 - что есть нерациональное расходование ресурса.

Comment: Быть участником — право, быть модератором — обязанность :) Примерно так. Участник в любой момент может просто на месяц свалить. *В моем понимании*, модератор так поступить не может, он лицо должностное...

Comment: @Harry Не может быть обязанностью то, что не прописано в договоре/правилах и то, что не предусматривает санкций. Да вы сами видите, что модераторы могут точно так же на месяц "сваливать" и *ничего*. Так что ничего "должностного" тут нет, только попытка SE обрамить это как "поработайте на нас забесплатно сколько сочтете нужным, спасибо-пожалуйста". А дальше уже каждый сам решает, сможет ли он потратить сил меньше, чем получить профитов (в широком смысле).

Comment: Спасибо, ваша точка зрения как кандидата очень интересна.

Comment: Мне всё же кажется, что @Harry хотел получить именно какие-то реальные, а не гипотетические истории. Так как любые волонтёрские дела подразумевают работу в меру своих сил и желаний. И часть, выделенная **жирным** в этом ответе, кмк, очевидна. Успехи работы реальных модераторов предлагалось раскрыть и [раньше](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6077/176217). Но их активность, к сожалению, в этой части сейчас страдает. Не могу сказать, что в этом плане дотягивает до упомянутых 2,5 из 5.

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован об "обязанностях", мне кажется это его в корне подрывает. По крайней мере на текущий момент - никаких обязанностей де факто нет - каждый из 5 модерирует ровно столько, сколько пожелает.

Comment: [по теме](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337431/383809). Исходя из моего опыта модерирования, этого процесса более-менее придерживаются.